# What is the maximum string input in crypt() function?

Tags: php, php-5.3

I think I have reached the limit for `crypt($string)` at 72 chars. Here is the code:

```
<?php   
$p = '0123456789abcdefghij0123456789abcdefghij0123456789abcdefghij0123456789++';
var_dump($p);

$salt = '$2y$12$' . substr(str_replace('+', '.', 
            base64_encode(sha1(microtime(true), true))), 0, 22);
var_dump($salt);

$hash = crypt($p, $salt);
var_dump($hash);

var_dump($hash === crypt($p, $hash));
var_dump($hash === crypt($p.'a', $hash));
var_dump($hash === crypt($p.'-or-anthing else beyond this...', $hash));
```

Output is:

```
string(72) "0123456789abcdefghij0123456789abcdefghij0123456789abcdefghij0123456789++"
string(29) "$2y$12$nLe2d618C6YN0FQ0vODGvz"
string(60) "$2y$12$nLe2d618C6YN0FQ0vODGvutzCR5h0ngWmDSXtFdSt2dPAW5vgPd1e"
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

Is it normal behaviour that 72 char is the maximum input string?

Comment: I **think** it depends on the hashing function used (specified by the salt)

Comment: I vaguely remember someone else asking the same question before. Will try to find his answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, after investigating a little, the bcrypt algorithm is limited to 72 characters. Anything beyond that gets truncated.

However, being a hashing algorithm designed for password hashing, I doubt you'll ever need to worry about that limitation.

Comment: where can i read more about that limit? i really need to be sure, that 72 characters are the limit. can character be UTF-8/16/32 and still count as one character ?

Comment: @glavi: Yes. `crypt` is binary safe. I did not find any official resources on that though.

Comment: ok, i will limit password length input. thanks for your trouble.

Comment: For a detailed explanation of why this is, check out the answer on the [Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39849/does-bcrypt-have-a-maximum-password-length)